# difference between vmovq_n_f32() and vdupq_n_f32()

Tags: arm, neon

I'm now learning arm neon. I find that vmovq_n_f32() and vdupq_n_f32() seems to do the same thing, they all initialize a float32x4_t variable with some value. So what's their difference?

I have tried using both functions, and they output the same value.

Comment: [ARM vdupq_n_f32](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vdupq_n_f32) and [vmovq_n_f32)](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets/intrinsics/vmovq_n_f32) give identical descriptions.  [Gcc instrinsics](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.4/gcc/ARM-NEON-Intrinsics.html) list vdup.32 q0, r0 as the target for vmovq_n_f32().  So I think it is syntax and they map to the same opcodes.  It just lets you use either name?

Answer (score 0):

They map to the same thing, so there is no difference